# Unexpected behaviour for loop with "until"

Tags: scala, for-loop, nullpointerexception

Recently, I've started learning Scala for school project. The assignment says that we have to delete elements of an unsorted array, without leaving "holes" in the array. I've made the following code:

```
private var _list = new Array[NAW](20)
private var _highestIndex = 0;

def removeAllbyName(name : String): Unit = {
 for(i <- 0 until _highestIndex){
   if(_list(i).name == name)
     deleteByIndex(i)
 }
}

def deleteByIndex(i : Int) : Unit = {
  if(i != -1){
    for(x <- i until _highestIndex){
      _list(x) = _list(x + 1)
    }
    _highestIndex -= 1
  }
}
```

I filled the array with 10 instances, the highestIndex will be 10 and after the first removal 9. But the for-loop still keeps counting to 9, which results in a null-pointer exception, even though we use "until". The debugger does recognise that _highestIndex is 9. Can somebody please explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0 until _highestIndex` only gets evaluated once.

```
for (i <- 0 until _highestIndex) {
  if (_list(i).name == name)
    deleteByIndex(i)
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
val range = 0 until _highestIndex
for (i <- range) {
  if (_list(i).name == name)
    deleteByIndex(i)
}
```

You can see that the range is determined only once.

You could try using a while loop instead, or a guard in your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for-loop` inside `deleteByIndex` like this to avoid `exception`

```
  for(
      x <- i until highestIndex
      if (x + 1) < highestIndex
     )
     list(x) = list(x + 1)
```